# Angular 2 notify when http request is finished

Tags: angular, observable

I am populating a table by linking an array with an `ngFor` in the template.

However, as the array is populated asynchronously from an HTTP request I am noticing a slight rendering delay when new data is loaded into the array from the remote server which causing a 'flashing' while the table gets repopulated.

This does not happen if I repopulate the array locally so I assume the problem is that as each item gets loaded into the array from the observable, the table is updating.

I would like to wait until the data is fully loaded before it gets rendered in the template. The approach I have been trying is to load the data into a temp array, get notified when the temp array is fully populated and then add that to the array that is linked to the template.

I believe the third parameter of subscribe is supposed to do something on complete so I have tried to used that. See below...

```js
this.dataService.callApi()
    .subscribe(
        response => this.arrayTemp = response.content,
        error => this.response = error.text(),
        () => this.array = arrayTemp
    );
```

However, this is not working as I expected and I am still seeing the rendering problem. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: How are you rendering the table? With `*ngFor`?

Comment: `Http.get()` currently delivers only one event, therefore using the 1st or the 3rd callback usually doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You can just add a `do(...)` like this.dataService.callApi().do(value => console.log(value)).subscribe(...)` and you'll see what gets delivered (you need to import `do`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a boolean 'loaded' inside the subscription.

Set 'loaded' default to false and use a 'ngIf="loaded" arround your table, and then set it inside subscription.

```
this.loaded = false;
this.dataService.callApi()
    .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.arrayTemp = response.content;
          this.loaded = true; 
        }
    );
```